# What does "anchor identity and hope" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/anchor_2

> Stories are deeply rooted in the human experience. It is through story that we can see into each other’s souls, and apprehend the soul of the organization. The stories that both individuals and organizations tell about themselves **anchor** identity and hope.

[Source](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=Stories%20are%20deeply%20rooted%20in%20the%20human%20experience.%20It%20is%20through%20story%20that%20we%20can%20see%20into%20each%20other%E2%80%99s%20souls,%20and%20apprehend%20the%20soul%20of%20the%20organization.%20The%20stories%20that%20both%20247%20individuals%20and%20organizations%20tell%20about%20themselves%20anchor%20identity%20and%20hope&source=bl&ots=oxN1vdDoZP&sig=ACfU3U1UfIKERVRFka8y5wOgJRi84dMTfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG6tri4cnhAhURdXAKHaSICXwQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Stories%20are%20deeply%20rooted%20in%20the%20human%20experience.%20It%20is%20through%20story%20that%20we%20can%20see%20into%20each%20other%E2%80%99s%20souls%2C%20and%20apprehend%20the%20soul%20of%20the%20organization.%20The%20stories%20that%20both%20247%20individuals%20and%20organizations%20tell%20about%20themselves%20anchor%20identity%20and%20hope&f=false).

Comment: It's not clear to me where there is confusion. By the definition you've pointed to, it means that the stories put identity and hope "firmly in position." It's a metaphor.

Comment: It's used figuratively, the same as the first sentence of your quote:
"Stories are **deeply rooted** in the human experience".

Comment: It is helpful to simplify the sentence -- **The stories anchor identity and hope** -- to understand that ***the stories*** is the subject and ***anchor*** is the verb.  Then you can decode the **metaphoric** meaning of the word "anchor".

Answer (score 1):

[The definition used for "anchor" (as a verb):](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anchor)

> to secure firmly

Answer (score 0):

"Anchor" is used mostly metaphorically, telling that "identity and hope" are secured (to the organization, culture...) with the help of the stories (in the same way an anchor secures a ship to the water bed).